# Turn object path to actual object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, yup

I have a complex state value for my forms in React App. For validation, I'm using Yup. After validation, Yup is returning a string of the object path of invalid value like this:
`locationAvailability.availabilityPerDay.thursday.start`. How can I turn this into something like this:

```
locationAvailability: {
  availabilityPerDay: {
     thursday: {
      start: true
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Currently, I'm using string.split('.') method on the object path, turning it into an array and then creating an object manually, but I am not really satisfied with this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do probably

```js
const object = 'locationAvailability.availabilityPerDay.thursday.start'.split('.').reduceRight((obj, prop) => {
  if (obj) {
    return {
      [prop]: obj
    }
  }
  return {
    [prop]: true
  }
}, null)

console.log(object)
```